# I'm getting errors trying to install angular2 moment

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular2-moment

The instructions here didn't work for me:

https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

I did

```
npm install --save angular2-moment
```

worked fine, then I attempted to do:

```
typings install --save moment
```

but got `typings: command not found` error, then I did the import in my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
```

included it in my module declarations and entry components array, 
ran the build and got:

> "Error: Unexpected module 'MomentModule' declared by the module 'AppModule' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment';
@NgModule({
    declarations:[/**...**/]
    imports:      [BrowserModule,MomentModule], // did you update this line this works for me 
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
    providers:[
       /**
       ...

       **/
    ]
})
```

This works check this link https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts line 115

Comment: No I hadn't put it there.. It worked after I put it in imports and removed it from the declaration and entryComponents arrays.